# Easy Admin 3. How to use one CRUD Controller for to write to 2 entities

Tags: symfony, easyadmin, easyadmin3

EasyAdmin 3 (Symfony)
Is it possible to use one CRUD Controller for write to one table and write some data to another table?

Comment: A crud controller is bound to one entity, however your new/edit form could embed another one that would create another entity, thus creating different row in different table (Index page).

Comment: Thank you! But can I  see somewhere example realisation this method?

Comment: Just look into how you can create custom field using custom form type, it's just regular symfony form management

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really specific but you can override any CRUD action you want as cited in the documentation and persist data to other entities if you need to.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/EasyAdminBundle/crud.html#customizing-crud-actions